# Can't reset password for Azure SQL server (greyed out)

Tags: sql, database, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I've got a brand new SQL database inside my new Azure server and I want to allow access to some users that I have designated with the 'Contributor' role, so they can write some SQL code.

However, they cannot authenticate: the connection strings say {your_password_here}, but I can't reset the password!

[here: the connection strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGrLr.png)

[here: the greyed out 'reset password'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJdf6.png)

As you can probably tell I don't understand how databases work. I want these people to sign in with their account into the database and edit at the level of permissions assigned.

Comment: That button doesn't apply to user connections. You need to create actual SQL Server users and provide their usernames and passwords.

Comment: Check [Create accounts for non-administrator users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/logins-create-manage?view=azuresql#create-accounts-for-non-administrator-users) in the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple terms, the contributor role will not allow them to gain access to the database, there are two levels of permissions:

- The management plane e.g. Contributor role
- The Data plane, access to the database engine.

When you created your SQL Server, you had to type in an administrator account, you can either use that account to create a SQL Login for your users, or you can integrate your server with Azure AD. With Azure AD users can log in using their Single Sign-On authentication.

**To integrate SQL Server with Azure AD:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell#provision-azure-ad-admin-sql-managed-instance

To create a database user based on the users' SSO use the following syntax:

```
CREATE USER <email> FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER:
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 2):

Within your SQL Server, go to Azure Active Directory and uncheck "Support only Azure Active Directory authentication for this server". The "Reset Password" will then be enabled.

[image: here: AAD in SQL Server]